# Check if directory is a Git root in one command

Tags: git, bash

I need

- check if the current directory is under Git version control
- if it's the Git root
- do the above it in one-line shell script which should exit with 0 on success

Answer (score 6):

Using `git-rev-parse` is the way to go. Just make sure you compare it appropriately with `PWD`, and redirect standard error to `/dev/null`:

```
[[ $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null) = "$PWD" ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
[ $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) == $(pwd) ]
```